# adding properties to an existing object inside an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I am picking an array with few object on it from an external file.

Using:

```
app.controller('mycontroller',  function($scope, $http) { 
$http.get("file")
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.lols = response.data;     
});});
```

This will give me back something like:

```
 $scope.lols = [
{
    prop1: "h1",
    prop2: "h2",
},
{
    prop1: "g1",
    prop2: "g2",
},}
```

Now I want to add a prop3 in each of the objects how should I do it ? If I had the data into my js file I will do it manually but picking the data from an external file...

I have tried simply doing:

```
app.controller('mycontroller',  function($scope, $http) { 
$http.get("file")
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.lols = response.data;
    $scope.lols.push = [
    {prop3: "h3"},
    {prop3: "g3"}
    ]
});});
```

But it has not worked...

Thanks for any help or link explain it.

**SOLUTION:**
https://jsfiddle.net/d3c96e0z/3/

Comment: What is `$scope.games.push = [`?

Comment: can u be more clear on to which array has to modified ? . games array or lols arrays . :)

Comment: Please find here what I am trying to achieve https://jsfiddle.net/d3c96e0z/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `prop3` to be a sibling of `prop1` and `prop2`?
If so you can do it either **hard-coded** like:

```
$scope.lols[0].prop3 = "h3";
$scope.lols[1].prop3 = "g3";
```

Or in a more **dynamic way**:

```
var newProps = ["h3", "g3"];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.lols.length; i++) {
  $scope.lols[i].prop3 = newProps[i]; // assuming the length of both arrays is the same size;
}
```

**The problem with your approach:** With `push` you're creating a new index in the array instead of adding your properties to existing indexes.

Comment: each object has a diferent prop3 value

Comment: and from where do you get those values? Then I can tell you how to add them dynamically. What's the data structure of the source?

Comment: I updated my answer with a dynamic solution assuming your source is an array with the same length.

Comment: Michael , thanks for your help, this is a more clear example of what I am trying to achieve [link](https://jsfiddle.net/d3c96e0z/)

Comment: that means you know the length of the array you receive and you can create a new array with the same length, right? So you can use the dynamic example above just change the content of newProps like: var newProps = ["megaman", "jesus!"]; and put the code after  $scope.lols = response.data;  of course.

Comment: I think it should be $scope.lols.length instead of $scope.games.length You still didn't explain where $scope.games come from. But yes besides of that it should work like that.

Comment: BTW: The example you've given is not valid JavaScript by the way. You're having syntax errors. As far as I see you're missing at least a )}; for closing the controller.

Comment: Finally working! You start, will study what you have done for future projects! Big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help you:-

```
var lols = [
{
    prop1: "h1",
    prop2: "h2",
},
{
    prop1: "g1",
    prop2: "g2",
}
]

Object.keys(lols).map(function(key,index){
        var lol = lols[key]
      lol["props3"]="g3"
      console.log(lol)
})
```

JS fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/bps7zzf8/

Comment: Please find here what I am trying to achieve https://jsfiddle.net/d3c96e0z/

Answer (score 0):

try like, [Here is working example](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/9885/)
 `$scope.lols.push({prop1: "h3",prop2: "g3"});`

Comment: With that you add a new object to the array but i want to keep the same object I have extracted from the external files and just add 1 more property yo each one

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add `prop3` in each object can try this process:

```
// assume that you know "lols" length. here let 2 so add 2 values for prop3

$scope.prop3Values = ["yellow", "red"];

$scope.lols = $scope.lols.map(function(e,index) {
    e.prop3 = $scope.prop3Values[index]; // assign your value in prop3
    return e;
  });
```

then your `lols` will be look like

```
$scope.lols = [
{
    prop1: "h1",
    prop2: "h2",
    prop3: "yellow"
},
{
    prop1: "g1",
    prop2: "g2",
    prop3: "red"
}]
```

Comment: If the value of the prop3 need to be for example "yellow" in the first object and "red" in the next object how would it be?

Comment: Please find here what I am trying to achieve https://jsfiddle.net/d3c96e0z/

Comment: if you know length of `lols` array and what value need to add for `prop3` then add all values in an array and assign it by using index. see my update answer @noway

Answer (score 0):

Keep the properties to be added in a array of objects and then loop over the $scope.lols and add each property according to the index;

```
$scope.propertyJson=[{prop3: "h3"},{prop3: "g3"}];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.lols.length; i++) {
 angular.forEach($scope.propertyJson[i], function(value, key) {
  $scope.lols[i][key] = value;
 });
}
```